# Different error handling for different endpoints

Tags: python, flask, connexion

I have error handlers in my app. I add these using connexion's add_error_handler which is calling flask's register_error_handler. I wish to restructure the error data that is returned by my endpoints in this handler. However, since I have so many unit tests reliant on the old structure, I wish to implement the new error structure for a subset of endpoints first. I believe I can do this as follows:

```
from flask import request

new_endpoints = ("/new_endpoint",)

def is_new_endpoint():
    return request.path in new_endpoints


def my_error_handler(e):
    if is_new_endpoint():
        return FlaskApi.response(new_error_response(e))
    else:
        return FlaskApi.response(old_error_response(e))
```

Is there another approach to doing this? The problem I have is that I believe that the is_new_endpoint function might get messy.

I define my endpoints in a yaml file, and for each endpoint, I have an operationId which specifies the python function associated with the endpoint. Maybe I could decorate these functions to define them as new and have this information available in the error handler. Could this be a possible alternative approach? Could I use flask.g for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. But as far as I understood the main idea was to avoid describing routes paths in the application config(`new_endpoints = ...`).

Yes. Looks like you can use `flask.g` + custom `decorator`. Here is an example:

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask, request, g


app = Flask(__name__)


def new_endpoint_decorator():
    def _new_endpoint(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def __new_endpoint(*args, **kwargs):
            # register request path
            if not hasattr(g, 'new_endpoints'):
                g.new_endpoints = set()
            g.new_endpoints.add(request.path)
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return __new_endpoint
    return _new_endpoint


@app.route('/old_endpoint')
def old_endpoint():
    raise ValueError('old_endpoint')


@app.route('/new_endpoint')
@new_endpoint_decorator()  # endpoint will use a new error format
def new_endpoint():
    raise ValueError('new_endpoint')


@app.errorhandler(ValueError)
def error_handler(error):
    # checking flask.g on new_endpoints
    if hasattr(g, 'new_endpoints') and request.path in g.new_endpoints:
        return f'new error: {error}'
    return f'legacy error: {error}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('localhost', debug=True)
```

Let's check:

```
curl http://localhost:5000/new_endpoint  # new error: new_endpoint
curl http://localhost:5000/old_endpoint  # legacy error: old_endpoint
```

It's probably best to replace `@new_endpoint_decorator()` to `@legacy_response()` because old routes usually don't change. So you can just add decorator to all legacy routes 1 time and forget it.